# How to get "non-action" keyframe data via Python?

Tags: python, keyframes, timeline

I have animated a camera, changing the position and FOV between keyframes (see picture below)

I can reach the keyframes related to `CameraAction` via Python:

```
>>> len(bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera'].animation_data.action.fcurves)
9
```

However, the changes to the camera FOV are not included in `CameraAction`.

How can I reach the FOV keyframes via Python?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation data aka `animation_data` are localized where the data are.

For FOV, this is in camera data. You can check:

```
len(bpy.context.object.data.animation_data.action.fcurves)
```

Identically, for a mesh, if you had animation data for shape keys (for instance), this is:

```
bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

Comment: unfortunately, the suggestion to use `bpy.context.object` only works with the current selected object in Blender - which requires an user to click on objects. I am looking for an automated solution where I can loop scene objects and, in this case, discover if they have a FOV change. In addition, this answer does not explain the difference between accessing objects via `bpy.context.scene.objects[...]` or `bpy.context.object` - they seem to be different and I do not understand the significance between the two. Simply put; is there a way to refer to my camera object via code instead?

Comment: The question was about finding where is the animation data concerning fov. If your question has other aspects, you should have mentioned it. But, anyway, concerning finding the camera(s), you can loop over `'bpy.data.cameras' which is directly the data part and get the animation data.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your initial answer. `bpy.context.object` confused me. I understand now I can access the data via `bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera'].data.animation_data.action.fcurves` (with a emphasis on `.data`). The `bpy.context.object` just means "this current object" and was used as another way to refer to the same object.

Comment: np, and yes, that's it. And looping over all cameras can be done over bpy.data.cameras (which are the "data" parts of the camera objects).